# Proving that $F_{x,n} = \left\{y \in \mathbb R^p :|y-x| \leq \dfrac {1}{n}\right\}$ is contained in $G$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^p$. Let $A$ be the subset of $G$ whose coordinates are  all rational numbers.

Then, show that

> For each $x$ in $A$, there is a smallest natural number $n_x$ such that if $n \geq n_x$, such that $F_{x,n} = \left\{y \in \mathbb R^p :|y-x| \leq \dfrac {1}{n}\right\}$ is contained in $G$

**Attempt:** Given that $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^p$,  which means for each $x$, there exists an $r>0$ such that all those points $y \in \mathbb R^p$ which satisfy $|x-y|<r$ belong to $G$.

We need to prove  that there exists a natural number $n_x$ such that $r=1/n_x$.

Did I infer it correctly? I don't see how the required condition is a necessity. May be $r =1/\sqrt {101}$ will serve just better?

Where did I make a mistake? How do I move forward?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^P$ and $A$ is a subset of $G$, then according to the definition of an open set we can say that:

$\forall x \in G, \exists \epsilon_x>0: B(x,\epsilon_x)\subset G$ , where $B(x,\epsilon_x)$ is an open ball of centre $x$ and radius $\epsilon_x$.

So, $\forall x \in A, \exists \epsilon_x>0: B(x,\epsilon_x)\subset G$.

It is obvious that we have a descending sequence of sets $\ldots\subset F_{x,n+1}\subset F_{x,n}\subset F_{x,n-1}\subset \ldots \subset F_{x,2}\subset F_{x,1}$.

Let's consider an arbitrary $x \in A$. For this $x \in A$, one of these two cases occur.

$\bullet$ $\epsilon_x>1 $

Then, it is obvious that $F_{x,1}=\bar{B}(x,1)\subset B(x,\epsilon_x)\subset G$, where $\bar{B}(x,1)$ is a closed ball of centre x and radius $1$.

Since we have the descending sequence $\{F_{x,n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, it is true that $F_{x,n}\subset G, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. So we can pick the smallest one ($n=1$).

$\bullet$ $0<\epsilon_x\le1$

According to the [**Archimedean property**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) , for every $\epsilon>0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a natural number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.

In our case, we can say that for this $0<\epsilon_x\le 1$, there is a natural number $n_x \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\frac{1}{n_x}<\epsilon_x$.

So, we have that $F_{x,n_x}=\bar{B}(x,\frac 1{n_x})\subset B(x,\epsilon_x)\subset G$.

Apparently, all those natural numbers that belong to  $A=\{n_x,n_{x}+1,n_x+2,\ldots\}\subset \mathbb{N}$ are  acceptable. Though, we choose the least element of $A$, which is $n_x$.